# How do i add an empty line before a line only from the second one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code the variable w is StreamWriter:

```
var c = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox));
foreach (ComboBox cc in c)
{
    if (c.Count() == 1)
    {
        w.Write("ComboBox Name " + cc.Name + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        w.Write(Environment.NewLine + "ComboBox Name " + cc.Name + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    foreach (string ccc in cc.Items)
    {
        w.WriteLine("Classes " + ccc);
        CMBXWMICLASSES.Add(ccc);
    }
}

w.Close();
```

The problem is in this place:

```
if (c.Count() == 1)
{
    w.Write("ComboBox Name " + cc.Name + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
else
{
    w.Write(Environment.NewLine + "ComboBox Name " + cc.Name + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

What i want is that the first line with ComboBox Name will be with an empty line only after it. For example:

CombBox Name: daniel

something here....after the empty line

And then in the next time where there is ComboBox Name it should add empty lines from both sides:

something here then empty line:

ComboBox Name: sharon

something here after empty line

But what i get is already in the first line that write ComboBox Name an empty line before it.

This is how i see it in the text file:

Empty line

ComboBox Name cmbxOption

Classes Win32_1394Controller
Classes Win32_1394ControllerDevice
Classes Win32_BaseBoard

ComboBox Name cmbzxfdgdfg

Classes....
Classes....
Classes....

The problem is with the ComboBox cmxOption that there is an empty line before it and it shouldnt be.

Comment: Can you post the desired output ?

Comment: Just a little sidenote here, instead of telling us what the `w` variable is, why not just name it properly? Your code would speak much more by itself if you used relevant names like `streamWriter`,`allComboBoxes` or `item` instead of `w`, `c` or `ccc`.

Comment: So you want no line for first, 3 lines between each, and finally 2 line after the last is that it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking the count of all comboboxes:

```
var c = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox));
foreach (ComboBox cc in c)
{
  // c.Count will return a count of all combo boxes in the collection
  // so this is only true if there is only 1 combo box.
  if (c.Count() == 1)
```

The simplest option is to use a flag or iterator to check where you are:

```
var c =  GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox));
bool handledFirst = false;

foreach (ComboBox cc in c)
{
  if (handledFirst)
  {
    // Most likely case first
    w.Write(Environment.NewLine + "ComboBox Name " + cc.Name +
            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
  }
  else
  {
    // This is first time through, don't forget to set the flag
    w.Write("ComboBox Name " + cc.Name + Environment.NewLine +
            Environment.NewLine);
    handledFirst = true;
  }
  [...]
}
```

The other option would be to use an iterator count (declare an `int` and increment it each time through), or switch to a standard for loop.